# Натяжка на WP - как реализовать вывод страницы на странице?

Tags: wordpress

Натягиваем на ВП данный html шаблон

стиль шаблона вывод страниц на главной странице в окне

подскажите как лучше на WP реализовать вывод такой же этих страниц с разделов чтобы это были при обычные wp страницы(блог, записи, страница с портфолио)?

Comment: В целом, так же, как вы обычно организуете вывод данных Wordpress в любом шаблоне. Изнанка (Worpdress) та же самая, снаружи только чуть менее привычный HTML, но это не должно смущать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам понадобится установить плагин [Easy Fancybox](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/) и сделать нижеследующее.

В подвале добавить блоки под модальные окна.

```
function action_wp_footer(){
    ?>
    <div id="popups" style="display: none;">
        <?php // post1 ?>
        <div class="fancybox-hidden" style="display: none;">
            <div id="post1_popup">
                <?php do_shortcode('[read_post title="Привет, мир!"]'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php //end of post1 ?>
        <?php // post2 ?>
        <div class="fancybox-hidden" style="display: none;">
            <div id="post2_popup">
                <?php do_shortcode('[read_post title="Новая новость"]'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php //end of post2 ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer' );
```

В примере организован вывод двух записей: "Привет, мир!" и "Новая новость". Таких блоков может быть любое количество.

Использован собственный шорткод `[read_post]`, который создается такой функцией в `functions.php`:

```
function read_post_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $p = get_page_by_title($atts['title'], 'OBJECT', 'post');
    if ($p)
        return do_shortcode($p->post_content);
    else
        return '';
}
add_shortcode('read_post', 'read_post_shortcode');
```

Ссылки в меню на указанные блоки должны иметь такой вид:

```
<a href="#post1_popup" class="fancybox">...</a>
<a href="#post2_popup" class="fancybox">...</a>
```

Чтобы указать класс `fancybox` для пункта меню, на админ-странице редактирования меню нажмите справа вверху `Настройки экрана` и поставьте галочку возле `Классы CSS`.